# How do I unfold a specific line?

Tags: folding

Let's say that I have a file of 100 lines, and all of the lines are folded. How would I unfold only line number 51?

- foldmethod is `manual`
- All lines were folded with `1,$fold`

Comment: Running `:%fold` creates a single fold over the whole file. You can only open or close the fold, not parts of it. You could use smaller folds or subfolds, though.

Comment: I see. So I'd have to figure out the range of the fold, unfold the whole thing, then refold the pieces above and below.

Answer (score 1):

To unfold (or open the fold) for only line 51, you would type `:51 foldopen`. See `:help foldopen` for more info.

Comment: That command unfolds all the lines. To be clear, foldmethod is manual, and all lines were folded with 1,$fold.

Answer (score 0):

`zf` to fold a selection. This command takes a motion after it or a previous selection.

Eg.

`zfj`to fold the line you're on and the one below.

or

after selecting a bunch on lines in visual mode (`v`) use

`zf` to fold the selected lines.